# How to identify the ACL owner

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

> If I set multiple users with different permissions using setfacl for a
>   file, will there be many ACL Blocks for the same file. If so how to
>   identify the ACL owner.

Answer (score 1):

The `getfacl` utility will show you as owner of the ACL whichever user owns the file on the filesystem and of course you can see that from the output of `ls -l` too.

For example, try the following:

```
touch j
# clean slate, just default entries
getfacl j
setfacl -m user:`id -un`:rwx j 
# note how now you have a named acl entry with rwx
getfacl j                          
sudo chown lp j  
# the following will fail, you have no acl access                                        
setfacl -m user:`id -un`:rw- j
# but this will work, because of 1st setfacl
echo "foo" >> j
```

So, owner of the file and the owner of the ACL boils down to the same thing.